# Stamp the existing pdf file and save it again

Tags: asp.net

I want to stamp first page of any existing pdf file with any text enter by the user and save it again or overwrite the file. I found some article about it on google but all are either create a new pdf file or save the stamped file in new pdf file. I want to save the stamping in existing file.
Have you any suggestions or source code.

Thanks in advance
Dinesh Kumar

Comment: If you can save the stamped file in new PDF file then you can always copy it over the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/)

You can manipulate PDFs with it.